# custom transitions for specific layouts in Nuxt.js

Tags: nuxt.js

In my Nuxt.js app one of my nested routes has a completely different layout than the rest of the page. To make the transition less jarring I want to apply a custom transition to this page/layout only. It's a combined zoom/fade animation, kind of like the windows in Windows 10, so it looks like the new page is opening on top of the old one. Once the opening transition is done, the old page is removed from the DOM, since it's a transition. Exit is obviously reversed, with the entering page being loaded underneath the exiting one and after that the exiting transition is played, giving the illusion that the page is closing on top of a page that was there all along.

I had this setup working in a normal Vue app by wrapping the top-level `<router-view />` in a transition element and specifying the transition CSS only on that special page (scoped).

With Nuxt, I can't get it to work like that. I have the layout transition set up in my `nuxt.config.js`:

```
layoutTransition: {
  name: "layout",
  mode: "in-out",
},
```

If I set the transition CSS globally, I get the effect on every page (obviously), which I don't want. If I set it scoped to the target layout, it doesn't work at all.

Workarounds that I can think of but that I don't like:

1) Ditch the layout system by using one layout for all pages and then using standard page transitions. I don't like it because that means defining my layout manually on every single page, as far as I can tell. This will lead to a lot of duplicated code and awkward code structure, which is just asking for trouble. I would have to fight Nuxt's automatic routing a lot, which I don't want to do, because I like the automatic routing.

1b) Of course I could also come up with a layout component and pass the whole site content to that as a slot, which would make the layouting easier and less error prone. That way I'd basically create my own layout system and circumvent the one from Nuxt. So I would change the architecture of the whole site, add boilerplate and bypass parts of the framework just to have one transition on one single page. Feels like overkill.

2) Use an actual overlay instead of a seperate page. I don't like it because it doesn't map to a route, therefore removing the ability to bookmark that page or use the history for navigation. Also the page "underneath" can be somewhat complex, so for performance reasons I don't want it loaded (yea, I could use `v-if` to remove it, making the code even more fiddly).

3) Just don't use a transition. So far it's the only one on the whole site, so at least it would be consistent to not have a transition. However, since the rest of the site is pretty uniform with a persistent header and footer and lots of stuff on the screen and the "special" page is mostly empty with just a text editor to allow for focused working, that transition is pretty jarring and it looks like you left the site. Also, I'm not willing to accept that the answer is "it's just not possible" when I already had it working in plain Vue (no pun intended).

In short: I *really* want this to work properly, without fighting Nuxt or compromising the user experience. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you figure out anything? Really strange that nuxt developers didn't noticed this issue till now.

Comment: Unfortunately not. So far I have removed the transition, since my site is still in the prototyping stage. Maybe I won't need the transition in the final design. Also, the next version of vue-router might have an interesting feature for overlays that change the route. (https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/pull/153). I'm still open for solutions though.

Comment: Well, I ended up using a single layout only, hope the future nuxt versions will support layout transitions better, or maybe I'll try to contribute myself :)